# $_GET not working in HostPapa environment

Tags: php, get

I pass a json encoded array in the URL that looks something like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/php/edit.php?event={...a bunch of values...}
```

In the edit.php page I retrieve the array like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['event'])){ 
    $eventData = json_decode($_GET['event'],true); #return an array
}
```

This works beautifully in my local **wamp** environment (on **localhost**).
This works beautifully in **GoDaddy** environment.
**DOES NOT** work in **HostPapa** environment. It does not seem to see the 'event' parameter, isset() is not returning true.

I am completely baffled and don't even know what to say or ask HostPapa support (if anything).
Does anybody have any idea what the cause for this could be?
Is there a setting of some sort that I should be looking at?
I would really VERY MUCH appreciate some help. Please.

**Update**: I only encounter this issue when passing the array. When I don't use an array, it works!

**Update #2:** @Phil suggested a LimitRequestLine issue and I passed that on to **HostPapa support** (3X) but they kept ignoring it. I finally created 2 test pages for them to mimic the problem outside of my application. A test page in root with a button which when clicked opens a second page with array parameter, in root/php/ demonstrating the fact that $_GET is not working.
 HostPapa support ignored that also.
 
HostPapa supports final email to me read (among other things):

> “It seems that you are using incorrect code, hence you are requested
>   to thoroughly check the code present inside your files.”

and closed my ticket.

During the creation of the 2 test pages for support I learned this:

1. When the second test page is in the php/ directory to mimic my application, $_GET **does not work**.
2. If I put both pages into the root directory and therefore **shortening the URL including query string by 4 characters**, $_GET **works** just fine.

So unfortunately in this particular case the solution is to change my hosting provider to someone that will actually provide support. As a small business I cannot afford these lengthy downtimes, it costs me money and does not instill confidence in my clients when my app doesn't work.
A big **THANK YOU** to **@Phil** for his help!

Comment: what does var_dump($_GET); return when you pass anything as a get request?

Comment: i think the problem from their php settings ..ask them or check if you can change php.ini from your control panel

Comment: @KyleThomas in this particular case var_dump($_GET); returns: array(0) { }

Comment: @mohade Yes, I have a php.ini file in my directory. It currently contains only a timezone entry. I believe settings in this file override the general settings set for the site by the provider. What setting would be responsible for this behavior?

Comment: You say it works when it's not JSON. Are you encoding the value correctly? For example, instead of `?event={"foo":["bar","baz"]}` it should be `?event=%7B%22foo%22%3A%5B%22bar%22%2C%22baz%22%5D%7D`

Comment: @Phil Yes, I am encoding the value correctly. It works in 2 out of 3 environments, which is why I think it might be some sort of setting.

Comment: How long is the request URL including the query parameter? You might be running into a modified [`LimitRequestLine`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) directive (assuming Apache)

Comment: Thanks @Phil, I have passed this question on to HostPapa support. I am waiting to hear back from them. Unfortunately I often feel that they appear to know even less than me, so this could take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HostPapa support finally fixed the issue:

> We have increased "**suhosin.get.max_value_length**" value for your
>   account and this issue has been fixed now.

It only took them 9 days (during which the app was obviously down) and my reopening the ticket twice as well as sending in a complaint.

FYI: I switched hosting provider 5 days ago to **PeoplesHost**.